# d3js: d3.json() throwing unexpected error

Tags: d3.js

I'm building a data visualization using some of [Sunlight Foundation's data APIs](http://sunlightfoundation.com/api/). I'm getting a weird error though. Here's my (very simple) `d3.json()` call:

```
            d3.json(url, function(error, json) {
            if (error) return console.warn(error);
            data = json;
            console.log(data);
            });
```

And I get  this console error:

[image]

I really don't know how to interpret this. FWIW, my URL takes this form:

```
var url = 'https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?zip=' 
+ userText + '&apikey=[my key]';
```

And when I visit it manually, in my browser bar, it's fine - I see the JSON I want:

[image]

I've also experimented with a few other URLs (both with and without `https`), and they're working fine - `d3.js` runs without breaking. I'm really at a loss, as it just seems to be this specific URL - and it doesn't seem to be happening from Sunlight's end, since I can see the JSON I want when I visit it via my browser bar.

Sorry for the vague question - that error message (especially the highly meaningful `:`...) is just completely mysterious to me! And it seems to be a break in the `d3.js` itself. Hoping someone else has run into this error. :/

**Updated to add**: So it looks like nature of the error shifts slightly if I'm using a locally-hosted or online version of d3.js. When I'm using a local host:

```
            <script src="d3/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The d3.js file breaks on the line with `request.open(method, url, true);` being the problematic line.

When I use the d3js.org host of d3.js, it breaks on line 1 of d3.js: `!function () {`.

[image]

In both cases (local or online host), my other d3 methods (`d3.select("body").append("p").text("Test.")`) work fine.

**Updated, a second time**: And [here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anarres/oswqtrg1/). Though I'm getting slightly different errors: on my local machine, I get "Test!" to show up (as a check that d3 is not breaking entirely). On the JSFiddle, I don't - and I also get a slightly different error message in my console.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, the API is [CORS- and JSONP-enabled](https://sunlightlabs.github.io/congress/#client-side-support):

> The Congress API supports CORS for all domains, so requests using any modern 
>   JavaScript library inside any modern browser should Just Work.
>
> If CORS isn’t an option, you can provide a callback parameter to wrap the
>   results in a JavaScript function, suitable for use with JSONP. This can be 
>   used to make cross-domain requests to the Congress API within the browser, 
>   when CORS is not supported.

And the code you've provided works. So it seems the error is originated from elsewhere. At least your can try with JSONP.

```js
var url = 'https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?zip=20004&apikey=opendataday'; 
d3.json(url, function(error, json) 
{
  if(error)
  {
    return console.error(error);
  }
  console.log(json);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sigh - yes, CORS is fine (as I've run into some CORS blocks earlier). What's strange is the "blank"-ness of the error. It just refers me to that line in the `d3.js`: `request.open(method, url, true);`. I've tried switching between local and online hosts of d3, as well as it's min and non-min form. No luck.

Comment: Scratch that - when I switch to the d3js.org-hosted `<script>` source of d3.js, it breaks on the first (!) line of `d3.js`! Other d3 methods work fine.

Comment: Can you update your question with a snippet of code that breaks on first line?

Comment: I mean an executable snippet that can throw the error you're talking about. A native SO snippet like in my answer, or at [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/) or elsewhere. Unless this strange error is reproducible, one can barely tackle it.

Comment: Ah ha - thanks for that. Added a JSFiddle (didn't realize `opendatakey` was a public API for them - useful!).

Comment: Hm, jsfiddle wraps your code in ``window.onload = function(){...}``. So there's no window-level ``firstTry`` that you can assign to button's ``onclick``. In general, using inline handlers is a bad practice. Assign handlers in your script. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ts8g54vs/), which still has the request working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64108/discussion-between-angela-and-saaj).